# No MX records?! Zone file issue. Shopfiy vs. self-hosted email

Tags: dns, email, mx, shopify

One of my hosting clients has a website: www.vincedevito.ca.

Some time ago, he decided to use Shopify as his primary website, but I still host his email.

Therefore, I set up a DNS Zone with GoDaddy.

```
; SOA Record
VINCEDEVITO.CA. 3600    IN  SOA ns77.domaincontrol.com. dns.jomax.net (
                2015112604
                28800
                7200
                604800
                600
                )

; A Records
@       600     IN  A   23.227.38.32
mail    3600    IN  A   71.19.154.96
webmail 3600    IN  A   71.19.154.96

; CNAME Records
ftp 3600    IN  CNAME   @
www 3600    IN  CNAME   vince-devito-shoes.myshopify.com

; MX Records
mail    3600    IN  MX  10  mail.vincedevito.ca
```

And here is the the Zone file on my server

```
$TTL    86400

@   IN  SOA ns.vincedevito.ca. foo.gmail.com. (
            1448609688  ; Serial
            10800   ; Refresh
            3600    ; Retry
            604800  ; Expire
            10800 ) ; Minimum

vincedevito.ca.              IN NS   ns.vincedevito.ca.
ns1.vincedevito.ca.          IN NS   vincedevito.ca.
ns2.vincedevito.ca.          IN NS   vincedevito.ca.
ns.vincedevito.ca.           IN A    71.19.154.96
vincedevito.ca.              IN A    71.19.154.96
webmail.vincedevito.ca.      IN A    71.19.154.96
mail.vincedevito.ca.         IN A    71.19.154.96
ipv4.vincedevito.ca.         IN A    71.19.154.96
ns1.vincedevito.ca.          IN A    71.19.154.96
ns2.vincedevito.ca.          IN A    71.19.154.96
ftp.vincedevito.ca.          IN CNAME    vincedevito.ca.
*.webmail.vincedevito.ca.    IN CNAME    vincedevito.ca.
www.vincedevito.ca.          IN CNAME    vincedevito.ca.
lists.vincedevito.ca.        IN CNAME    vincedevito.ca.
store.vincedevito.ca.        IN CNAME    vince-devito-shoes.myshopify.com.
vincedevito.ca.              IN MX       10 mail.vincedevito.ca.
vincedevito.ca.              IN TXT   "v=spf1 +a +mx -all"
shop.vincedevito.ca.         IN NS    ns.shop.vincedevito.ca.
ns.shop.vincedevito.ca.      IN A     71.19.154.96
shop.vincedevito.ca.         IN NS    ns1.rede.ca.
shop.vincedevito.ca.         IN NS    ns2.rede.ca.
```

All http traffic is now successfully directed to his Shopify site.

Email is another story. If I try and send him a test message from my Gmail account, I get this

> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>   foo@vincedevito.ca
>   Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)
>   Technical details of temporary failure:
>   DNS Error: **MX lookup of mydomain.com returned error DNS server returned general failure**

The same goes for any other external email service... messages never hit my server.

But If I send an email from another account on the same server, the email is delivered immediately. (I have other reasons to conclude that this is strickly a DNS issue... the email service itself is working perfectly).

No MX records?!

```
# dig vincedevito.ca MX
;vincedevito.ca.               IN      MX
```

IntoDNS certainly sees that there is a problem:

> Oh well, I did not detect any MX records so you probably don't have any and if you know you should have then they may be missing at your nameservers!

UltraTools thinks so as well

> Sorry, there was a problem.
>   No MX record were found for the domain/email foo@vincedevito.ca.

In fact, there is international consensus that something is fubar'd

> https://www.whatsmydns.net/#MX/vincedevito.ca

I have gone over my steps a dozen times and I've talked to GoDaddy tech support twice (the second guy actually tried to help). Can anyone see some issue with my Zone settings?! I sure would appreciate some help!

Comment: Use *dig +trace vincedevito.ca any* to see which set of records you are dealing with. You have given us two sets of DNS settings and only one can be the SOA. Using dig +trace will absolutely tell you who is the SOA and where to work. It will also show you what records show up and the settings.

Comment: Thanks for  your response, @closetnoc. I ended up getting this sorted by changing the MX record with the registrar, but I appreciate your tip.